# Integrate Pylint with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pylint

I'm trying to integrate pylint with pyCharm, but I want it to be an online tool.

What do I mean ? I want it to detect errors and checking code standards when I write the code.
Until now, I have done it by clicking "Tools --> External Tools --> pylint".
There is an option to do this ? or maybe call the Pylint when I run the script ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Under `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...` you can see the Configuration on the right Side. At the Bottom is a Section called `Before launch: Activate tool window` where you can hit the green plus Button and configure pylint to be executed before the run.

Comment: After i do this its running pylint(That's good !) but it stops after that, it doesn't run my script.

Comment: mhhh than I can't help you anymore... But it should run the Script after that

Answer (score 1):

I am just going through this myself - I think there are some earlier answers about setting up an external tool to produce a report, but this exists and sounds like exactly what you want.

[Pylint-Pycharm](https://github.com/perses76/pylint-pycharm)

> Pylint-Pycharm is a wrapper around Pylint that formats file paths in the Pylint output in a way that Pycharm can parse. This allows you to go to finding directly by clicking on the provided link.
>
> The tool accepts the directory of a virtual environment as parameter and requires the paths of one or more Python files as input. The Python files/modules and all additional command line parameters are handed over to Pylint.

To configure as an 'external tool' in Pycharm (after you've run Setup.py):

```
command: pylint-pycharm
arguments: $FilePath$
```

[you can also pass in a virtualenv with --venv=, and other params for pylint such as your own pylintrc file]

```
directory: $FileDir$
```

Now the messages contain a link to the line in question.

To use straight pylint, configure per these instructions:

https://www.mantidproject.org/How_to_run_Pylint

Answer (score 0):

Roberto Leinardi has recently created a pylint plugin for pycharm which really works and integrates well into the IDE:

Easy to install from the repositories, full instructions under: https://github.com/leinardi/pylint-pycharm

I have a short yet a happy experience with it so far! Kudos to Roberto.